# Is it possible to install a 32bit Java JDK/JRE with Scoop?

Tags: scoop-installer

Is it possible to install 32 bit versions of Java Buckets with Scoop?

I've searched the different Java versions with

```
scoop search jre

scoop search jdk
```

But I can't see an option to choose for a 32 bit version.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to install the 32 bit version of any program using the `--arch` or `-a` (architecture) flag. For example:

```
> scoop install oraclejre8 -a 32bit
Installing 'oraclejre8' (8u281) [32bit]
dl.tar.gz (68.5 MB) [=========================================================================================] 100%
Checking hash of dl.tar.gz ... ok.
Extracting dl.tar.gz ... done.
Linking ~\scoop\apps\oraclejre8\current => ~\scoop\apps\oraclejre8\8u281
'oraclejre8' (8u281) was installed successfully!
```

I have also tried it with one of the jdks available:

```
> scoop install adopt13-hotspot -a 32bit
Installing 'adopt13-hotspot' (13.0.2-8) [32bit]
OpenJDK13U-jdk_x86-32_windows_hotspot_13.0.2_8.zip (179.7 MB) [===============================================] 100%
Checking hash of OpenJDK13U-jdk_x86-32_windows_hotspot_13.0.2_8.zip ... ok.
Extracting OpenJDK13U-jdk_x86-32_windows_hotspot_13.0.2_8.zip ... done.
Linking ~\scoop\apps\adopt13-hotspot\current => ~\scoop\apps\adopt13-hotspot\13.0.2-8
'adopt13-hotspot' (13.0.2-8) was installed successfully!
```

However, you'll want to [do a quick search](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Java/search?q=jdk%2032bit) to check which of the jres/jdks have a 32 bit option, as not all of them do.

Don't forget to add the bucket first with `scoop bucket add java`.

If you want to install both 32 and 64 bit versions of the same jre/jdk, there's no way to do so with the current version of scoop [according to this issue](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/issues/4329). But as one user suggests it is possible to copy one of the json manifests, rename it to `xxxxx-x86` and then install it again with the `-a 32bit` argument. However doing so will lose the autoupdates provided by the bucket, which isn't ideal. It would be possible to create your own 32 bit bucket if you wanted to by following the [instructions in the wiki here](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/wiki/Buckets#creating-your-own-bucket).